# object to ArrayList<String> unchecked cast

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

Compiling my code with -Xlint I found this:

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
found   : java.lang.Object
required: java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>
                    ArrayList<String> msgData = (ArrayList<String>)element;
```

This is the code:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> msg = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
//add some data to msg
Iterator i = msg.iterator();
while(i.hasNext()) {

    Object element = i.next();
    ArrayList<String> msgData = (ArrayList<String>)element;     
}
```

how should the cast be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Iterator needs a type as well, like this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> msg = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
//add some data to msg
Iterator<ArrayList<String>> i = msg.iterator();
while(i.hasNext()) {
    ArrayList<String> element = i.next();
}
```

On a side note, it's better to program to interfaces, not to implementations. Thus, you'd write:

```
List<List<String>> msg = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
//add some data to msg
Iterator<List<String>> i = msg.iterator();
while(i.hasNext()) {
    List<String> element = i.next();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your iterator should be something like

```
Iterator<ArrayList<String>> i = msg.iterator();
```

Btw you can use for-each loop for it:

```
for (ArrayList<String> sublist : msg) {
    ....            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> msg = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
//add some data to msg
for (ArrayList<String> msgData : msg) {
   //do something
}
```